# Ajax based dependent exposed filters in view

Tags: 7, views

I have 5 content types viz **CType1**, **CType2**, **CType3**, **CType4** and **CType5** .

In **CType1** I have two fields
Field A
Field B

In **CType2** I have two fields
Field C (node reference - Field A)
Field D

In **CType3** I have one fields
Field E (node reference - Field D)

In **CType4** I have one fields
Field F (node reference - Field D)

In **CType5** I have one fields
Field G (node reference - Field D)

I have created one view and in that view I have created views exposed filters ,Here I am filtering data based on filter (drop down selection) selection.

Here I have to load second drop down (or second filter values) values based on first drop down value and third drop down value based on second drop down value.(like hierarchical select)
Here all drop down values are node references values (From above content types).

I have tried views dependent filters module for this, but no result.

Any help will be appreciated?